# What is the data structure for sql server analysis service's cube data storage?

Tags: sql-server, data-structures, ssas, cube

I want to know that what is the used data structure for storing cubes and what is the mechanism for reading data from that.

Comment: See: [Programming AMO OLAP Basic Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345091.aspx). Cubes are stored into multidimensional form. You can update/retrieve data using AMO and AMOMD ([MDX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145514(v=sql.105).aspx) queries). Use [DMX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895242.aspx) for data mining.

Answer (score 2):

Overall this is a pretty complex answer. For details on exactly how SSAS structures its data, I would recommend the book "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services Unleashed (Paperback)". It contains a lot of the details on the various stores that SSAS uses to structure it's data.  It's not for faint of the heart so be prepared for lots of geeky minutiae :-)

Saying this, the basics are that:
- the data structure for SSAS involves a proprietary architecture that surrounds the creation of many files. The primary is the *.data file that is per partition and contains the data itself
- there are many index, map, and aggregate files as well that allows SSAS to query aggregations of the data vs scanning the data file directly
- there are also header (vs data) files for each of these file types. These contain metadata on what exists in those files.

Comment: so you are saying .data file contains data as well as the mapping indexes of that data also. Actually I am trying to understanding what exactly does a data file contains

Comment: There are separate map, agg, and index files.